# is there a way to support a scalapb grpc and play app in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a grpc scala application that needs to have an aws ELB health check.   Usually i do this using Play /health.

Is there a way to run both a grpc and Play application listening on different ports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly, as of now (Play 2.5.x) you'll have problems with gRPC and Play coexisting in the same process because they have conflicting netty versions. Consider using akka-http for your healthcheck endpoint; it is also lighter and does not have any effect on your project's structure.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a Play 2.6.11 app to use a gRPC client by using a `shaded` version of grpc-netty dependency. This dependency does not collide with Play's netty.

Change your dependency from:

```
"io.grpc" % "grpc-netty" % scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion
```

to:

```
"io.grpc" % "grpc-netty-shaded" % scalapb.compiler.Version.grpcJavaVersion
```

and do a `clean` & `compile`.

I found out about grpc-netty-shaded in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/TWa18IfZ5kA/702iWPGJAgAJ). It was introduced into grpc-java version 1.9 in [this pull request](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/2485).

Comment: How about gPRC server?